# What is $x_2$ if $x_1=18$, $x_{n+1}=\frac{10}3x_n-x_{n-1}$, and the sequence $(x_n)$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> What is $x_2$ if $x_1=18$, $x_{n+1}=\frac{10x_n}{3}-x_{n-1}$, and the sequence $(x_n)$ converges?

I don't see how this is possible. You are only given $1$ term and the formula needs $2$ terms to determine another term. Any ideas?

Comment: You could set $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: Of course, $x_0$ is also needed. If not, $x_2=\frac{10}{3}\cdot 18-x_0=60-x_0.$

Comment: $$x_2=6{}{}{}$$

Comment: Could you post a solution @did?

Comment: Hint: What do you know about the general solution of the recursion $x_{n+1}=\frac{10}3x_n-x_{n-1}$?

Comment: @Did I don't really know, but I found a (possible?) solution sketch. Can you validate this? If you let the second term be 18/x, the third term is 60/x-18. So, you can use this geometric series and get the quadratic 3x^2-10x+3=0. x=3. So, the second term is 6. Is that what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** The general solution of the equation is given by:

$$x_n = c_13^n + c_23^{-n}$$

Now can you prove that the sequence diverges, when $c_1 \not = 0$?

Comment: Umm, what is $c_1$ and $c_2$...? Is this really necessary? It converges.

Comment: @user406996 $c_1$ and $c_2$ are some constants that depend on the initial values of the problem. Using the fact that $x_n$ converges we can conclude that $c_1 = 0$ and using $x_1 = 18$ that $c_2 = 54$

Comment: @user406996 In fact we don't need $c_2$, as $x_n = c_23^{-n} = c_23^{-(n-1)}\cdot \frac 13 = \frac{x_{n-1}}{3}$

Comment: Ok. Thank you for a second solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

First let's write the characteristic equation:
$$r^2-\frac{10}{3}r+1=0$$
The solutions are $$r_1=\frac{1}{3}, r_2 = 3$$
So we have: $$x_n = \alpha_1*(\frac{1}{3})^n + \alpha_2*3^n$$
Now it should be clear that the series won't converge if $\alpha_2\neq0$.
So we can present $x_n$ as $\alpha*(\frac{1}{3})^n$

Let's use our initial condition:
$$x_1=\frac{1}{3}\alpha=18\implies\alpha=54$$
Now we know the formula of our recurrence: 
$$x_n=54*(\frac{1}{3})^n$$
Now substituting $2$ for $n$ we get:
$$x_2=54*(\frac{1}{3})^2=6$$